# IntelliJ IDEA Android app XML tags not found

Tags: android, android-layout, intellij-idea

[image: IntelliJ IDEA Preview of XML File]

**Issue:** IntelliJ can't find any XML tags (marked in red by IntelliJ)
**Steps followed:** Open IntelliJ -> Create a new project -> Android -> Empty Activity -> Let Gradle sync
**Surprising part:** The code compiles perfectly and even runs on an Android phone connected via ADB.

So, I believe it is an issue regarding the IDE and nothing else. Please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: So, somehow things are now back to normal
Two things I noticed were:
1) The problem went away once I accepted some licenses from SDK manager (but not sure how the app could compile without those)
2) Somehow the IntelliJ theme I use also has set the XML tags red (material design red as opposed to danger red), which is more confusing
3) Still don't know a concrete solution but for now everything is working fine :D

Comment: In most cases it happens due to installed plugins (material design in your case). Try [disabling](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) them if the issue remains.

It also makes sense to perform `(File -> Invalidate caches/restart)` in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had too same problem. First try cleaning the project Build>Clean. Then try clearing the cache and then restart your android project. For this goto File>Invalidate Cache and Restart.
Hope it solves!

Comment: It works for me now somehow (see comment on the question)
But not really sure how it came to be :P